# "Failed to deserialize object" Error occured while inserting object in ignite cache

Tags: java, caching, ignite

The following error occurred while inserting a pojoClass object on a string key. I have included all event types in the Ignite configuration.

I have tried `setStoreKeepBinary(true)` and also tried `igniteConfiguration.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true)` but the error isn't solved.

I'm using Apache Ignite version 2.1.

**Error logs:**

```
[2017-09-06 16:22:08,043][ERROR][tcp-client-disco-msg-worker-#4%null%]     [TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to unmarshal discovery data for component: 0
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@75b84c92
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:129)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:94)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:143)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:82)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.internal.DiscoveryDataPacket.unmarshalData(DiscoveryDataPacket.java:274)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.internal.DiscoveryDataPacket.unmarshalGridData(DiscoveryDataPacket.java:131)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.onExchange(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1820)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.processNodeAddFinishedMessage(ClientImpl.java:1985)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.processDiscoveryMessage(ClientImpl.java:1864)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.body(ClientImpl.java:1758)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Failed to find cache for name: CACHE
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.readResolve(GridCacheContext.java:2139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1148)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2036)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.readExternal(IgniteCacheProxy.java:2782)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:2076)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2025)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2125)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2125)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.GridEventConsumeHandler.readExternal(GridEventConsumeHandler.java:452)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:2076)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2025)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor$DiscoveryDataItem.readExternal(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1812)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:2076)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2025)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.readList(IgniteUtils.java:5299)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.readCollection(IgniteUtils.java:1739)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor$DiscoveryData.readExternal(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1727)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:2076)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2025)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:121)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find cache for name: CACHE
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.readResolve(GridCacheContext.java:2134)
    ... 49 more
```

**Cache Configurations :**

```
  CacheConfiguration<String, pojoClass> cacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration<>();
            cacheConfig.setName("CACHE");
            cacheConfig.setBackups(2);
            cacheConfig.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
            cacheConfig.setIndexedTypes(String.class, pojoClass.class);
        //  cacheConfig.setStoreKeepBinary(true);
            IgniteCache<String, pojoClass> Cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheConfig);
```

**code While inserting pojoClass object :**

```
PojoClass pojoObj = new PojoClass(key, name,jsonObject);
Cache.put(key, pojoObj);
```

**here PojoClass is :**

```
public class PojoClass{
@QuerySqlField
String key;
@QuerySqlField
String name;
@QuerySqlField
JSONObject jsonObject;
public PojoClass(String key, String name,JSONObject jsonObject) {
        this.key = key;
        this.name = name;
        this.jsonObject = jsonObject;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add code when you inserting pojoClass object on string key. Full reproducer will be helpful

Comment: I have mention it, Please check.

Comment: Are you sure that you run cache put from the same node and not inside Job or task? Could you share reproducer?

Comment: Yes, I am using same node to put data. Can you elaborate about "share reproducer"?

Comment: As you can understand, if you simply create Cache and right after it put some data in it, everything should work - there are a lot of tests for it. I'm asking you to write a small reproducer - for example, one java file, that will show behavior that you describe

Comment: I have tried but this Error is not producing in sample program.

Comment: So, that means that you have a wrong code and you provided a code snippet that doesn't show problem at all

Comment: I am working on 4-5 cache and I have given snippet of the cache where that error occurred. But when I tried same operation on cache (By creating example) with same configuration then error is not occurred.

Comment: But when run program with combination of other cache then that error is occured.

Comment: So, then you should write reproducer with all caches. It's impossible to reproduce anything with data that you provided

Comment: Above issue is resolved. This issue is occurred due to different node are used while performing operation.I was using different instance of Ignite (due to bad coding practice) . Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is solved after using same instance of Ignite while creating cache and performing Event functionality I was using different Ignite instance that was above issue occurs.